# Segregating data from pandas dataframe using tag types

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with a text file using a `pandas` in `python`. The file has text and numerical data, and is in the format shown in the picture shown below:

[image]

The actual text file corresponding to the above picture can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rlFCXeaJe6DmhwTcvXvlwgD7rYyyf2Ga/view?usp=sharing). I am importing this file in `pandas` using

```
df = pd.read_csv('dum.txt',sep='\t', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

I want to get separate matrices for separate tag types (`Tag1`, `Tag5`, `Tag6`) from this `pandas` dataframe. In particular, I would like to get columns 0, 1 and 2 which are grouped under the tag `Tag1` as one numpy array (of shape `(8,3)`), columns 3 and 4 which belong to `Tag5` as another numpy array (shape: `(8,2)`) and columns 5 and 6 (which belong to `Tag6`) as another numpy array (shape: `(8,2)`). How can I do this? I will really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What about df.groupby

Comment: pygo: How can I use df.groupby here to achieve the functionality that I want? I haven't used df.groupby very much. I will appreciate if you can give me an example of how I might use it here.

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Images are good but difficult to reproduce!

Comment: Sandeep: I have inserted a link to the text file in the recent version of the question. I hope this helps.

Comment: `df.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).Tag1.values` Should also work.

Comment: @Abhi: Your comment is super helpful also: I would like to use Tag values (like how you have mentioned in your answer). Please feel free to put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.values` with desired columns as:

```
df = pd.read_csv('dum.txt',sep='\t',header=[0,1],index_col=0)

df[['T1','T2','T3']].values

array([[1.1, 2.1, 3.1],
       [1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
       [1.3, 2.3, 3.3],
       [1.4, 2.4, 3.4],
       [1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
       [1.6, 2.6, 3.6],
       [1.7, 2.7, 3.7],
       [1.8, 2.8, 3.8]])

df[['T4','T5']].values

array([[4.1, 5.1],
       [4.2, 5.2],
       [4.3, 5.3],
       [4.4, 5.4],
       [4.5, 5.5],
       [4.6, 5.6],
       [4.7, 5.7],
       [4.8, 5.8]])

df[['T6','T7']].values

array([[6.1, 7.1],
       [6.2, 7.2],
       [6.3, 7.3],
       [6.4, 7.4],
       [6.5, 7.5],
       [6.6, 7.6],
       [6.7, 7.7],
       [6.8, 7.8]])
```

Or if you have indices [0,1,2] , [3,4] then:

```
df[df.columns[[0,1,2]]].values
array([[1.1, 2.1, 3.1],
       [1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
       [1.3, 2.3, 3.3],
       [1.4, 2.4, 3.4],
       [1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
       [1.6, 2.6, 3.6],
       [1.7, 2.7, 3.7],
       [1.8, 2.8, 3.8]])
```

OR:

```
df.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).Tag1.values
array([[1.1, 2.1, 3.1],
       [1.2, 2.2, 3.2],
       [1.3, 2.3, 3.3],
       [1.4, 2.4, 3.4],
       [1.5, 2.5, 3.5],
       [1.6, 2.6, 3.6],
       [1.7, 2.7, 3.7],
       [1.8, 2.8, 3.8]])
```

Comment: how are you processing the data file `dum.txt`

Comment: @Sandeep: Thanks, man! This is exactly what I needed. Your answer is super helpful.

Comment: @pygo: I have a data science pipeline which takes these numpy arrays as input.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa, `df = pd.read_csv('dum.txt',sep='\t',header=[0,1],index_col=0)`  is working on your terminal with python3? It gives me `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Its really amazing its giving index error with python3.6

Comment: @pygo I am using `pandas=0.23.3` and `python=3.6.6`.